# how to increase labels distance from main plot in heatmaply r

Tags: r, heatmap, heatmaply

I have a simple issue in **interactive heatmap in R**. I couldn't figure out how to increase margins (distance between x and y labels with main plot) in heatmaply?

I want to add a little bit of space in **ylab (province)** from heatmap. Could anybody help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WITzn.jpg)

Comment: Provide your code and maybe even sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the margins with `heatmaply` by using `margins`

Since you did not provide any code in your question, I will use an example plot using `mtcars` and changing the y-axis margins

```
heatmaply(mtcars, margins = c(0, 200, 0, 0))
```

[image: exmaple]

If you want to move the y-axis labels away from the graph, then that will be trickier. Currently, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this, however, here is a workaround. There is currently now way to move the y-axis labels in `heatmaply`. Overall, this is a poor workaround but it appears to be the best solution as of right now.

```
df <- mtcars
#extract the labels on the y axis. In this example mtcars y-axis labels are the row names
df2 <- as.data.frame(rownames(mtcars))
#you then have to add spaces to the end of the labels and then apply this to the dataframe you are using. 
rownames(df) <- paste0(df2$`rownames(mtcars)`, "            ")
#you can now run heatmaply on the new labels with added spaces
heatmaply(df)
```

[image: example2]

Overall, `plotly` has some great features however it lacks in tuneability. `heatmaply` has even fewer features than `plotly` so it makes it even harder to tune your graph the way you want to.